# Im trying to make connection between site on hosting and VPS

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, apache, http

Im trying to send data from php on site to node js that listening some port on VPS. When I make request with jquery ajax it returns what I want, but when Im making request with cUrl from php to server It returns nothing('') without some errors. In my linux console Im seeing that it hasnt got any request. cUrl request just go to emptiness... I tried many cUrl requests and it hadnt returned any result.
Can it be due to my hosting? Or maybe I makes something wrong?

```
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

//Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was

//deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.listen(5300, function() {

  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5300/');

});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.all('/push', function(req, res) {

console.log(req.body); // 18

console.log(req.method);
console.log(req.headers);
console.log(req.url);
res.status(200).json({data:req.body}); // will give { name: 'Lorem',age:18'} in response
});
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't tell what is wrong with the PHP that you haven't shown us.

Comment: `Can it be due to my hosting?` That's a possibility. Contact support.

Comment: open `tcp:5300` on the firewall... such non-standard ports are closed by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open port in my hosting admin menu.